# JDK6 -> JDK7 cant use com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl

Tags: java, maven, java-7, jdk6

we have the following case in the code which causes tests to fail when running with JAVA_HOME set to JDK7 instead of JDK6 (maven with source/target = 1.6)

```
javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl cannot be found
        at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newFactory(XMLInputFactory.java:239)
```

the code itself

```
private static final String SUN_XML_INPUT_FACTORY = "com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl";
private final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory;

public theConstructor() {
    // When deployed to WebLogic 10.3.5 it will use "weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory" which will
    // cause a StreamReader exception as it requires some input stream other than null.
    xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory(SUN_XML_INPUT_FACTORY, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

I suppose I should use something else than `private static final String SUN_XML_INPUT_FACTORY = "com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl";` but i don't know what.

Comment: u r saying that if at JAVA_HOME enviromental you set JDK 6 , the app is running normally?

Comment: It's almost never good to use java internal classes. The point of "internal" is that the implementation can change without notice.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for "newFactory", it might give you an Idea for how to find a reasonable replacement. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#newFactory()

Comment: Are you still deploying to WebLogic 10.3.5, otherwise it might be worth trying the "newFactory" without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I found after JDK6, the method:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newFactory(String factoryId,ClassLoader classLoader)
```

change it's program.

The parameter `factoryId` is not a classpath, but a key.

So I put a `stax.properties` file into my `$java.home/jre/lib/` file and the context is:

```
com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory=com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory
```

then my problem solved.

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory("com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory", this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```